# python pandas replacing column values conditional on string patterns and using split()

Tags: regex, pandas

long time lurker--I finally stuck to a project involving pandas and more than ever I need your help.

I have a dataframe like the following. Each row describe one retirement formula which may have more than one criteria (hence e1)

```
index    e0     e1 
1    62/10   NaN
2    age 55  NaN
3    67/10   age 70
```

I want to make a column age that describes the minimum age. I've defined patterns for how each criterion is described. For example,

```
 pattern1=r'.*/.*'

 pattern7=r'age.[0-9].*'
```

and I have pattern1-pattern7.

I used the following code to extract age portion of e0 to a new column age:

```
 df['age']=df['e0'][(df['e0'].str.match(pattern1)==1)].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('/')[0])
```

which gives me

```
index    e0     e1    age
1    62/10   NaN      62
2    age 55  NaN      NaN
3    67/10   age 70   67
```

I want to address other formats such as "age 55" (to extract 55, in this case), but I'm not sure how to go about. If I do

```
  df['age']=df['e0'][(df['e0'].str.match(pattern7)==1)].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' ')[1])
```

then it's clearly wrong because I'd overwrite what's already in age and I get

```
index    e0     e1    age
1    62/10   NaN      NaN
2    age 55  NaN      55
3    67/10   age 70   NaN
```

I've tried other variations as far as the syntax would allow me but to no avail.
I'm a Stata user and in Stata, I'd be using replace command conditional on regexm. I'm trying to learn Python and it's been a difficult journey! I'd appreciate any help on this.

I have another (hopefully) quick question in addition: I've used the following two lines to get rid of white space in both e0 and e1.

```
 option['e0']=option['e0'].str.strip()
 option['e1']=option['e1'].str.strip()
```

Is there a way to address them both in one line?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a response to your second question (you should stick to one question per post).

```
df.loc[:, ['e0', 'e1']].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

I'm not sure why you are calling the DataFrame 'option' when it was previously referred to as 'df', so I stuck with the latter.

Comment: thanks for your response. it's not working though and I'm not sure why. pattern7 gets picked up only when strip() is used and I used df['ind']=np.where(df['e0'].str.match(pattern7)==1,1,0) to create an indicator for pattern 7 is detected. with my old codes (two separate lines), i see some 1s but not with your suggested code.

Comment: I realized I was just viewing the data, not setting it. Thanks so much! works :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, here I pass a function that removes the `NaN` values and then calls `sum` which will concatenate the rows of data.

We can then call the vectorised `str` method `findall` with regex `\d+` which returns all numbers as a list.

We then apply another function to this that converts the str numbers to ints, puts these in a list and returns the smallest value:

```
In [37]:

def func(x):
    return x.dropna().sum()
​
def lowest(x):
    return min(list(map(int,x)))
​
df['min'] = df[['e0','e1']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1).str.findall(r'\d+').apply(lowest)
df
Out[37]:
   index      e0      e1  min
0      1   62/10     NaN   10
1      2  age 55     NaN   55
2      3   67/10  age 70   10
```

Breaking the above down so you can see what is happening:

```
In [38]:

df[['e0','e1']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
Out[38]:
0          62/10
1         age 55
2    67/10age 70
dtype: object
In [39]:

df[['e0','e1']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1).str.findall(r'\d+')
Out[39]:
0        [62, 10]
1            [55]
2    [67, 10, 70]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! this is an approach that I hadn't thought about and one that I'm likely to employ down the road. for age, I wanted the series [62, 55, 67] at the end, and the problem I'm having now is that I can't target just row2 when I apply split(' ').

Comment: Sorry you want highest age? just change `def lowest(x):
    return min(list(map(int,x)))` to `def highest(x):
    return max(list(map(int,x)))`

Comment: I can't pick the values from the list based on min and max because the expression format from which they came matters (I think it's not very clear from the examples I gave for sake of simplicity). I want to apply  df['age']=df['e0'][(df['e0'].str.match(pattern7)==1)].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' ')[1]) to only rows for which df['e0'].str.match(pattern7)==1) so as to not overwrite what was already in the age column...